# Trying to subclass but getting object.__init__() takes no parameters

Tags: python, inheritance, web.py

I'm trying to subclass web.form.Form from the webpy framework to change the behavior (it renders from in a table). I tried doing it in this way:

```
class SyssecForm(web.form.Form):

            def __init__(self, *inputs, **kw): 
                super(SyssecForm, self).__init__(*inputs, **kw)

            def render(self):
                out='<div id="form"> '
                for i in self.inputs:
                    html = utils.safeunicode(i.pre) + i.render() + self.rendernote(i.note) + utils.safeunicode(i.post)
                    out +=  "%s"%(html)  
                    out +=  '"<div id="%s"> %s %s</div>'% (i.id, net.websafe(i.description), html)
                out+= "</div>"
                return out
```

Now I'm getting this error `object.__init__() takes no parameters`:

[image: error traceback]

Comment: I recommend against using `super()` in situations where the methods aren't specifically designed for the use with `super()`.  Especially `__init__()` is almost never designed to work well with `super()`, so you should better use an explicit base class call `web.form.Form.__init__(self, ...)`.

Comment: @Sven that depends on whether it's a "new style" or "old style" class. You should always use `super` with new style classes (that inherit from "object"), but never with old style classes.

Comment: It's python 2.7, so still old style I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (web.py 0.37):

```
import web

class SyssecForm(web.form.Form):

    def __init__(self, *inputs, **kw): 
        super(SyssecForm, self).__init__(*inputs, **kw)

    def render(self):
        out='<div id="form"> '
        for i in self.inputs:
            html = web.utils.safeunicode(i.pre) + i.render() + self.rendernote(i.note) + web.utils.safeunicode(i.post)
            out +=  "%s"%(html)  
            out +=  '"<div id="%s"> %s %s</div>'% (i.id, web.net.websafe(i.description), html)
        out+= "</div>"
        return out

form = SyssecForm(web.form.Textbox("test"))
print form.render()
```

Your problem is because you might have outdated web.py, since web.form.Form inherits from `object` now: https://github.com/webpy/webpy/commit/766709cbcae1369126a52aee4bc3bf145b5d77a8

Super only works for new-style classes. You have to  add `object` in class delcaration like this: `class SyssecForm(web.form.Form, object):` or you have to update web.py.

Comment: Yes but what's the difference with calling your subbed class the same as your super class? I should be calling the same method no?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove your `__init__` method altogether, since you aren't really doing anything there, anyway.

Comment: While it is certainly true that the `__init__()` method is pointless, how should removing it make a difference?  The code should do exactly the same thing without this method, which is, throw an error.

Comment: Oh right, and don't instantiate it with any arguments.  Or don't all super method at all. It's hard to tell what the intent is here.

Comment: It's true, the init method doesn't do anything in the end. I just do not understand why it error's. The Form class does have the same init method with the same arguments.

Comment: @LucasKauffman: You never know what `super()` ends up calling – see my comment above.

Comment: @SvenMarnach removing it did fix it though :/

Answer (score 2):

The message tells you all you need to know. The super-class is object and its constructor takes no parameters. So don't pass it the parameters for your constructor since it doesn't know what to do with them.

Call it like this:

```
super(SyssecForm, self).__init__()
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like the superclass actually is `web.form.Form`.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I'm not saying you are wrong, I'm just saying that I don't understand what's happening yet.

Comment: I removed it and it works kinda, still some bugs but don't know if it's related. I thought by stating class SyssecForm(web.form.Form) that I inherited from this class. Are am I wrong? thx for the fast answer :)

Comment: @sven maybe web.form.Form has no init method, would that explain it?

Comment: @Lucas Keith's answer makes good sense. Why are you implementing this null method anyway.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, and none of its base classes.  But than I wonder why the OP is passing parameters to the constructor.  I don't think the correct fix is to ignore these parameters.

Comment: @sven perhaps OP is just a little confused. If that init is right then it is pointless. If it needs to receive parameters then it's missing a body.

Comment: No you are right, I don't really do anything there. The thing is Form has got an init method itself. So I don't understand why it wouldn't pass it to that class.