# How is `tuple.__init__` different from `super().__init__` in a subclass of tuple?

Tags: python

Please see the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

class MyTupleT(tuple):
    def __init__(self, contents):
        tuple.__init__(contents)
        self.len = len(contents)

class MyTupleS(tuple):
    def __init__(self, contents):
        super().__init__(contents)
        self.len = len(contents)

t = MyTupleT([0, 1, 2])
print(t.len, t)

s = MyTupleS([0, 1, 2])
print(s.len, s)
```

The output is:

```
3 (0, 1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tuple_init.py", line 16, in <module>
    s = MyTupleS([0, 1, 2])
File "tuple_init.py", line 10, in __init__
    super().__init__(contents)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

[The docs say](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)  that `super()` will:

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type

IIUC here `super()` is the same as `super(MyTupleS, self)`. Now the docs further say that

> The search order is same as that used by `getattr()` except that the type itself is skipped. The `__mro__` attribute of the type lists the method resolution search order used by both `getattr()` and `super()`.

Ohkay but then:

```
$ MyTupleS.__mro__
(__main__.MyTupleS, tuple, object)
```

So the `super()` line should first look within `tuple` to find `__init__` and tuple's `__init__` can certainly take one parameter (other than `self` of course) and is what is being called by the explicit `tuple.__init__` line. So why doesn't the `super().__init__` call work identical to that? Why is it trying to invoke `object.__init__` and failing?

IIUC one should only need to explicitly specify the superclass when one is worried that the inheritance hierarchy can change in a "dynamic execution environment" (phrase from the docs) and wants the method of a particular superclass to be called. But this error effectively makes it mandatory for the superclass to be specified. Why?

NOTE: This is different from [another similarly titled question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27566391/).

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with the question to get a downvote?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165405/#comment13041331_10165405 says `super()` and `__init__` don't go well together which is surprising because IIUC often one would want to call `super()` from `__init__`!

Comment: The first version only _appears_ to work because you've called `tuple.__init__()` without passing `self` (well, actually, you've passed the list `[0, 1, 2]` as `self`).

Comment: Oh yes when instance methods are called by a class name, we should manually pass `self`. Thanks for reminding that!

Comment: Downvoting legitimate questions which are receiving legitimate answers discourages non-experts like me from asking on SO for fear of downvote itself! 

Comment: Donno whether the downvoter recanted or someone else upvoted. Thanks either way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `tuple.__init__` it returns `object.__init__` because `tuple` has no custom `__init__` method and only inherits it from `object`. The first argument for `object.__init__` is `self` and what `object.__init__` does is nothing. So when you pass in `contents` it's interpreted as `self` and doesn't throw an Exception. However it probably doesn't do what you think it does because `tuple.__new__` is responsible for setting up a new tuple instance.

If you use `super().__init__` it also resolves to `object.__init__` but it already binds the current "self" as first argument. So when you pass `contents` to this function it's interpreted as additional argument which doesn't exist for `object.__init__` and therefore throws that Error.

Comment: Hi thanks for this but why should `tuple.__init__` resolve to `object.__init__` when tuple has its own `__init__`?

Comment: @jamadagni It doesn't have a "custom" `__init__` it just inherits it from `object`. That was what I meant. :)

Comment: Then something is wrong with PyCharm 2017.1.1 showing me `def __init__(self, seq=()): # known special case of tuple.__init__` under `class tuple(object):` of `builtins.py`.  Is that only an artificial Py file and really it's all inside the C implementation?

Comment: @jamadagni I only looked at the [source code for tuple and that doesn't define an `__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c#L840). That means it inherits it from `object`. But it does have a `__new__` method (a few lines later, it's called `tp_new`).

Comment: but then how does the `MyTupleT` store `contents` if the call to `tuple.__init__` isn't doing the lifting? Is it because `tuple.__new__` is implicitly called with `contents`?